# Setting Multiple alarms in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, alarmmanager

I've made an alarm activity in android studio, and I've only made one text view for alarm to be set, but I don't know how to change it so that I can have at least 3 alarms to set, I've tried adding more text views but when I set an alarm the value just appears in both text views, they override, I've been trying for an hour now, I also tried to change broadcast number but i messed up because I didn't really know how to do it, I would really appreciate the help,this is my alarm acitivty code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Alarm extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    private TextView mtimetxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
        mtimetxt = findViewById(R.id.timeTxt);

        Button opentimeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.opentimeBtn);
        opentimeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment timepicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                timepicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Time Picker");
            }
        });
        Button cancelalarmBtn = findViewById(R.id.cancelalarmbtn);
        cancelalarmBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cancelAlarm();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);//i want the second to be 0 when i set the alarm
        updateTimeText(c);
        startAlarm(c);
        /*TextView timetxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTxt);
        timetxt.setText("Hour: "+hourOfDay+" Minute :"+minute);*/
    }

    //creating the methods cancelalarm,updatetime and start alarm here
    private void updateTimeText(Calendar c) {
        String timeText = "Alarm Set For : ";
        timeText += DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(c.getTime());//we take the time and change it to a formatted string,it will also take into account if device is in 24or 12hour mode
        mtimetxt.setText(timeText);
        /*Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm Is Set to "+timeText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/


    }

    private void startAlarm(Calendar c) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
        //check if the alarm is set for a period in the past
        if (c.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {//this line compares the time set to the current time
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);//the alarm will be set for next day now
        }
        //initialize the alarm
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);//wil wake up device if it goes off
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 3000, 6000, pendingIntent);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Is Set to " + DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(c.getTime()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#28B1E3"));
        toast.show();
    }

    //cancel method
    private void cancelAlarm() {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);//this will cancel the pending alarm
        mtimetxt.setText("Alarm Cancelled");


    }
}
```

and the XML for it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Alarm">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/opentimeBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open time picker"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.452"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.611" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Alarm Set"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/opentimeBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.44"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.85" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelalarmbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel alarm"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.521"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/opentimeBtn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.639" />

   


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

when i press cancel both alarms get cancelled but i removed the second textview from this code since it didnt work, any ideas how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the behaviour of your onTimeSet overridden method. Right now it will always update the same textview when an alarm is created, you need to store these in some way. Whether that's a list, a map etc. You'll need that if you want to access them individually later (like you would to cancel or display them one at a time).

You also need to change the cancel alarm method, in both cases the Pending intent you are passing is how the Alarm manager determines which alarm to cancel. If you're passing the same values when creating and cancelling all of the alarms they will all match when the AlarmManager cancels them.

Comment: thank you for your reply but i jsut dont really know how to yet,its very confusing to me, the toturial i followed did that but i need more than just one alarm to be set,and i'm new to this so i'll try to see how to make your solution work